# bash replace multiline text in file, with pattern

Tags: bash, file, sed, edit

Hi I need to edit some file but I din´t want to do it manually, I know that using sed command I can edit files using command line, but in this case, I don't know how to match the pattern to edit. for example I have this file:

```
(
    AMI1
    {
        type            patch; // <- relpace patch by cyclicAMI;
        nFaces          1350;
        startFace       2433406;
    }
    inlet
    {
        type            patch;
        nFaces          1125;
        startFace       2434756;
    }
    outlet
    {
        type            patch;    
        nFaces          1125;
        startFace       2435881;
    }
    AMI2
    {
        type            patch;    // <- relpace patch by cyclicAMI;
        nFaces          2850;
        startFace       2440606;
    }
)
```

And I want to edit **ONLY** the AMI keys to look like this:

```
(
    AMI1
    {
        type            cyclicAMI;      // <-- Replaced
        inGroups        1(cyclicAMI);   // <-- Add
        nFaces          1350;
        startFace       2433406;
        matchTolerance  0.0001;         // <-- Add
        transform       noOrdering;     // <-- Add
        neighbourPatch  AMI2;           // <-- Add AMI2 in AMI1
    }
    inlet
    {
        type            patch;
        nFaces          1125;
        startFace       2434756;
    }
    outlet
    {
        type            patch;
        nFaces          1125;
        startFace       2435881;
    }
    AMI2
    {
        type            cyclicAMI;       // <-- Replaced
        inGroups        1(cyclicAMI);    // <-- Add 
        nFaces          2850;
        startFace       2440606;
        matchTolerance  0.0001;          // <-- Add 
        transform       noOrdering;      // <-- Add
        neighbourPatch  AMI1;            // <-- Add AMI1 in AMI2
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not overly elegant, but working.

```
state=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "${line// }" in
        AMI[12]) state=${line##*AMI}
                 echo "$line";;
        typepatch\;*) echo "        type            cyclicAMI;"
                      echo "        inGroups        1(cyclicAMI);";;
                  else
                      echo "$line"
                  fi;;
        \}) if [ "$state" != 0 ]; then
                echo "        matchTolerance  0.0001;"
                echo "        transform       noOrdering;"
                echo "        neighbourPatch  AMI$((3-state));"
                echo "    }"
                state=0
            else
                echo "    }"
            fi;;
        *) echo "$line"
    esac
done < textfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the result in the closing bracket of `inlet` and `outlet` key and the last parenthesis, are missing

Comment: @efirvida oops! Fixed.

Comment: thanks a lot, the missing end parenthesis was my mistake by removing the last empty line. THANKS!!, now all is ok

Comment: Hi, I did another fix, of you code, following the idea of your previous fix, because all the patches were replaced by cyclicAMI and not only that I need, but thanks again